# getView method not working correctly - adding extra blank row

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to build an `ArrayAdapter` that will output a row and the quantity of the item in that row. However I am getting an unwanted effect of an extra row being added every time.

I don't know what is wrong with my logic but I am sure that it is something small. Below is my `getView()` method:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_row, null);
    }

    item = dishes.get(position);
    if(lastItem != null){
    if(!lastItem.getName().equals(item.getName())){

    dishName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dishName);
    dishPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dishPrice);

    dishName.setText(item.getName());
    dishPrice.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

    dishQty = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dishQty);
    dishQty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQty()));
        }
    }
    else{
        dishName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dishName);
        dishPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dishPrice);

        dishName.setText(item.getName());
        dishPrice.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

        dishQty = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dishQty);
        dishQty.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQty()));

    }

    lastItem = item;
    return v;

}
```

Currently my output is like this

```
Chicken     QUANTITY
2.99            2
```

Then if I add a new item the quantity goes up as expected but it adds another row:

```
DISH NAME     QUANTITY
DISH PRICE        0
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong??

Every item in the list is of type `MenuItem` I increase quantity like this:

```
public void incQty(){
    qty++;
}
```

This is the `MenuItem` Array Adapter `getView()` where quantity is increase using a `NumberPicker`

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.menuitem_row, null);
        v.setFocusable(true);
    }

    // assign values to view
    final MenuItem item = this.menuItems.get(position);

    TextView nameView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    final TextView priceView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_price);

    nameView.setText(item.getName() + " ");
    priceView.setText("€" + String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

    // number picker
    np = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.numpick);
    np.setMaxValue(20);
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setValue(0);
    np.setFocusable(false);
    // calculation occurs when values are changed...
    np.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal,
                int newVal) {
            //Add to order - increment price
            if (newVal > oldVal) {
                total = (item.getPrice() * newVal) - item.getPrice()
                        * oldVal;
                Order.getInstance().addToOrder(item);
                item.incQty();
                amount += total;
                Order.getInstance().setAmount(amount);
                Toast.makeText(picker.getContext(), "Item Added: " + item.getName() + " Size: " + Order.getInstance().getOrderItems().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                confirmBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
            //remove from order - decrement price
            if (newVal < oldVal) {
                total = (item.getPrice() * oldVal) - item.getPrice()
                        * newVal;
                Order.getInstance().removeFromOrder(position);
                item.decQty();
                amount -= total;
                Order.getInstance().setAmount(amount);
                Toast.makeText(picker.getContext(), "Item removed: " + item.getName() + " Size: " + Order.getInstance().getOrderItems().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(Order.getInstance().getOrderItems().size() == 0){
                    confirmBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            }


            //update the text view price.
            price.setText("€" + String.valueOf(Order.getInstance().getAmount()));
        }
    });

    return v;

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that instead of Chicken's quantity going up to 3, a whole new row is added?

Comment: No the quantity of Chicken will increment to 3 but another row is also added with blank data every time

Comment: I don't think the problem is in your adapter code, you're going to have to give more code context.

Comment: Why are you using lastitem? the ArrayAdapter recycle itself automatic

Comment: I realize that I just thought that I needed a variable to record the last item to compare it to the next one in the array

Comment: @kabuko I see what you are saying but unsure what exactly I can share that will help you see what I am trying to do. Is there anything you would like me to post?

Comment: @Javacadabra It seems to me that your adapter code to create views is correct, but you're getting an extra item. This means the problem is likely where you're adding items to the adapter which is probably where you're increasing the quantity.

Comment: If you don't you care send me your project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the getCount() method of adapter. 
The getCount() method is the method that determine how many row will create from the getView() method.

For example if the getCount() return 5 you will got 5 rows on your listview. So please check your getCount() you might override it to make it return the correct number of row.